# How can I fix this regex in order to get html tag only from a particular url?

Tags: regex, shell, grep

Hello I have a html file with several img tags:

```
<img src="https://www.pokeyplay.com/imagenes/backend/publicidad.gif" alt="Publicidad" align="left" />
<img src="https://www.pokeyplay.com/imagenes/backend/spacer.gif" alt="sp" />
<img src="imagenes/backend/etiqueta-pyp-pokedex.gif" alt="P&amp;P Pok&eacute;Dex" width="184" height="100" />
<img src="imagenes/backend/spacer.gif" alt="sp" />
<img src="http://urpgstatic.com/img_library/pokemon_sprites/187.png" style="vertical-align:middle" />
```

In order to stract all img tags I am using the following regexp:

```
'<img[^>]* src=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>'
```

But I want to extract only all IMG tags from urpgstatic.com

How can do this?

I did several tries like this:

```
<img.*?src="(http[s]?:\/\/)urpgstatic.com?([^\/\s]+\/)(.*)[png]$"[^\>]+>
```

Thanks

Comment: Suggest you to use a HTML parser

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a shell solution, with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<img[^>]*(?=\"https?:\/\/(www\.)?urpgstatic\.com)\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gnCT36/1)

Also, this will work with grep

```
grep -iP '<img[^>]*(?=\"https?:\/\/(www\.)?urpgstatic\.com)\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>' index.html
```

Comment: This works but for any reason this dosent work with grep.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `grep` command:

```
grep -ioE '<img [^>]*src="https?://(www\.)?urpgstatic\.com/[^>]*>' file.html
```

```
<img src="http://urpgstatic.com/img_library/pokemon_sprites/187.png" style="vertical-align:middle" />
```

Though please remember that parsing HTML using regex may be error prone and using a HTML parser such as `DOM` in php is more reliable.

**RegEx Details:**

- `<img [^>]*src=`: Match `<img <anything-except->src=` text
- "https?://`: Match` http://`or`https://`
- `(www\.)?urpgstatic\.com/`: Match optional `www.` followed by `urpgstatic.com/`

Comment: This dosn't work I want to extract all html tag, no until src.

Comment: btw it is only searching for given pattern but output is complete `<img ..>` tag.

Comment: If you want to use `-o` flag then please check updated answer.